# Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException - Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to create a laravel project, using the terminal command `laravel`

I wrote `laravel new blog` and immediately appears the message `Crafting application...`

Seconds after that appears the message:

`[Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException]
  [curl] 7: Failed connect to 192.241.224.13:80;
  Operation timed out [url] http://192.241.224.13/laravel-craft.zip`

Any idea to solve it?

Comment: The host `192.241.224.13:80` is down. Nobody seems to have access. Install laravel from github instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Laravel by issuing the Composer create-project command in your terminal:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I was trying to create a laravel 5 app using my office network:

> [GuzzleHttp\Exceptio \RequestException]
>
> Error creating resource. [url] http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip [type] 2 [message] fopen(...../latest.zip): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  [file] /home/eagledev/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/StreamAdapter.php [line] 367

The problem was that in the company where I am working, they have a web protection software (sophos), that  was blocking laravel to download files from http://cabinet.laravel.com.

Double check if your network is using some web protection software or a proxy.